# Protobuf: Nesting a message of arbitrary type

Tags: protocol-buffers

in short, is there a way to define a protobuf Message that contains another Message of arbitrary type? Something like:

```
message OuterMsg {
    required int32 type = 1;
    required Message nestedMsg = 2; //Any sort of message can go here
}
```

I suspect that there's a way to do this because in the various protobuf-implementations, compiled messages extend from a common `Message` base class.

Otherwise I guess I have to create a common base Message for all sorts of messages like this:

```
message BaseNestedMessage {
    extensions 1 to max;
}
```

and then do

```
message OuterMessage {
    required int32 type = 1;
    required BaseNestedMessage nestedMsg = 2;
}
```

Is this the only way to achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not directly, basically; protocol buffers very much wants to know the structure in advance, and the *type* of the message ***is not included*** on the wire. The common `Message` base-class is an implementation detail for providing common plumbing code - the protocol buffers specification does not include inheritance.

There are, therefore, limited options:

- use different field-numbers per message-type
- serialize the message separately, and include it as a `bytes` type, and convey the "what is this?" information separately (presumably a discriminator / enumeration)

I should also note that some implementations *may* provide more support for this; protobuf-net (C# / .NET) supports (separately) both inheritance and dynamic message-types (i.e. what you have above), ***but*** that is primarily intended for use only from that one library to that one library. Because this is all *in addition to* the specification (remaining 100% valid in terms of the wire format), it may be unnecessarily messy to interpret such data from other implementations.

Comment: As I cannot know all the possible messages in advance, I will go for the separate serialization solution, using a `bytes` field, thank you

Answer (score 10):

The most popular way to do is to make optional fields for each message type:

```
message UnionMessage
{
    optional MsgType1 msg1 = 1;
    optional MsgType2 msg2 = 2;
    optional MsgType3 msg3 = 3;
}
```

This technique is also described in the official Google documentation, and is well-supported across implementations:
https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/techniques#union

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively to multiple [`optional`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#simple) fields, the [`oneof`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#oneof) keyword can be used since v2.6 of [Protocol Buffers](https://github.com/google/protobuf).

```
message UnionMessage {
  oneof data {
    string a = 1;
    bytes b = 2;
    int32 c = 3;
  }
}
```